# TFS Query: Can I compile a query to produce a list of any WorkItems I modified?

Tags: tfs

I would like to get a list of any WorkItems I modified in TFS using TFS query builder. Including **status** changes I made, "**assinged to**" changes and including those I made posts in **History**.

That looks to me like pretty basic and logical query, but couldn't fiugre out how to do that.

We're using the TFS web interface, but I guess it's identical to the query builder in VS's Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the work items you modified with the "Changed By" field (with “Was Ever” = your username):

[image]

This query returns all the work items you modified any field (State, Assigned To, etc.), but you **can't** create a query to get only work items when you changed them only specific fields.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, somehow I missed "Change By" even I was looking for that. Anyhow, this will NOT display desired results. I double checked it in the interface and as expected, it will only display WorkItems, where I was LAST person to edit them. It won't display WorkItems, where I edited some input and someone else made edits afterwards.

Comment: You’re right, my mistake, you need to use “Was Ever” and not “=“, see my updated answer.

Comment: Wow, that's the missing piece!